# Linux permissions error - they are set as "?"

Tags: linux, permissions

We currently have a file share between 2 Linux hosts and occasionally the permissions change to this:

```
d??????????   ? ?     ?      ?            ? share
```

and we are not able to read or write to the directory.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

It usually means that at some point the mountpoint was mounted correctly, but after some event it stopped having access to the remote filesystem.

It happens a lot with samba shares that changed their configuration and after applying them the client had no longer availibility to access the remote share (or even if the remote server stopped running for some reason).

Your logs should provide a more detailed explaination of what happened.